# Purrr's map function is not working with the names function

Tags: r

I am trying to dynamically create a list by mapping over a named character vector. In the example below, the map function correctly extracts the numeric value, but for whatever reason, the `names(.x)` function is not extracting the name.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
library(purrr)

dat <- c("yellow" = 3, "red" = 4)

dat %>% 
  map(~list("group" = names(.x),
            "value" = .x)) %>% 
  setNames(c("yellow", "red"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names are not preserved, that's one reason `purrr::imap` can be useful. It is analogous to `map2(x, names(x), ...)` (so therefore the value is in `.x` and name in `.y`):

```r
dat %>% 
  imap(~list("group" = .y,
             "value" = .x)) %>% 
  setNames(c("yellow", "red")) %>%
  str()
# List of 2
#  $ yellow:List of 2
#   ..$ group: chr "yellow"
#   ..$ value: num 3
#  $ red   :List of 2
#   ..$ group: chr "red"
#   ..$ value: num 4
```

The lack-of-names behavior of `map` can be confirmed by doing:

```r
> dat %>% purrr::map(~{browser();list("group" = names(.x), "value" = .x);})
Browse[2]> .x
[1] 3
```